# Parent dialog's OnHelp() override is always called instead of the active child dialog's override

Tags: c#, botframework

Building from the Enterprise Bot Template, we have 2 classes: MyDialog and MyReusableDialog. Both inherit from EnterpriseDialog and both override OnHelp() method.

MyDialog calls MyReusableDialog.  However while within MyReusableDialog, only MyDialog.OnHelp() is triggered.

MyReusableDialog.OnHelp() is never called unless it is the main/parent dialog. Is this by design, so does that mean that I can only handle OnHelp() from parent dialog?

Comment: Hi @Oyen; how are you calling MyReusableDialog from MyDialog?

Comment: I call it this way: `return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MyReusableDialog));`

Comment: Sorry, I unintentionally abandoned this one. Did you still need an answer on this?

Comment: Hi @DanaV thanks for following up. No, I handled everything from the base Interruptable class. It’s not ideal but works with what we need for now.